# a notation for convergeence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of complex functions and $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ for all $x$. If we put "for all $x$" behind the $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$, does it show that the convergence is uniformly convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The sentences

- $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$ for all $x$
- for all $x$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$

express the same fact. It's just a matter of rewriting the sentence in an equivalent form, which is a feature of English and many other languages.

You pass from pointwise to uniform convergence when you interchange the quantifiers in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the convergence, namely you replace $\forall \epsilon \forall x \exists \delta \cdots$ with $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta \forall x \cdots$.

Comment: If there is statement:there exists a sequence $f_n$ on $X$ such that $|f_n(ab)-f_n(a)f_n(b)| \to 0$ for all $a,b$ in $X$,is the convergence here pointwise or uniformly?

Comment: Written like this, the convergence is universally intended to be pointwise. I just means that once you fix values of $a$ and $b$, the sequence you wrote converges to $0$.